# Bind in asp.net core does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to get the values ​​from a **form** to save the object in a database

I have this action in MarcaController.
      [image: This was created by visual studio 2017]

And this View

[image: This was created by visual studio 2017]

And this Model

[image]

But when I try to create a new Marca the marca object in the create action has all the property that derive from the form set to null and I can't  understand why

Comment: what you have right there is a controller not a model class... you are getting wrong how binding works

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong to write @NicoRiff

Comment: Show us the model pls

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/710776/introduction-to-asp-net-mvc-model-binding-an-absol

Comment: Done @FailedUnitTest

Comment: press F12 in browser and make sure  `name` attribute of input element  matches to model properties

Comment: you may want to create model instead of binding entity directly

Comment: The names are correct @LP13

Comment: Your question needs to include the code, not images of it.

Answer (score 0):

Other option is create a separate model, with only properties you want and bind that model.

```
public class MyModel
{
   public int Iva {get;set;}
   public string Path {get;set;};
   // other properties
}
```

then in controller

```
public Task Index()
{ 
   var marca = _context.GetMarca();

   //map marca to MyModel here
   var model = new MyModel()
   {
      Iva = marca.Iva,
      Path = marca.Path
      // other properties
   }

   return Index(model);


}

public async Task<IActionResult> Create(MyModel model)
{
     var entity = _context.GetEntityByID(model.Iva);
     entity.Path = model.Path
     //map other properties
     await _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I prefer to bind different model instead of binding entity to view.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [frombody] attribute in controller function because httppost values come from body section of request.